# Bootstrap not loaded properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Title goes here.</title>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
    aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
     class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
 </div>
 </nav>
 <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" />

 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

I have started learning bootstrap with tutorial and following it. I have copied all the bootstrap CSS and js files to respective files and made sure they accessible to page(I can access them through view source). Now I copied bootstrap template and included needed jquery and bootstrap js ref in my jsp page but it is not displaying it as excepted. Attaching image [image]

Comment: you didn't close the </html> and you have 2 charsets listed

Comment: I have just copied the header and body script. html is closed properly. It is working when I replaced Bootstrap 4.0 css files with Bootstrap 3.7. Not sure why it is not working for 4.0(beta) or I may have to include different directive for the 4.0. For now I am Ok as it is working for 3.0. Thanks for your pointing